# trap command used to protect a file from Alt + f4

Tags: linux, bash, shell, signals, bash-trap

I want to know whether **Trap** command will be use to protect a file from **SIGKILL (ALT+ F4)** signal or not. If it is then the following command will does that?

```
trap ~/Desktop/left.py SIGABRT
```

I'm trying to abort the all signals which trying to close `left.py`.

Comment: You cannot protect any program from SIGKILL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ALT+F4 doesn't typically send a `SIGKILL`. If you're trying to prevent a process from being killed when its parent shell window is closed, you want something like...

```
nohup ~/Desktop/left.py &
```

...to trap the `SIGHUP`.

Or you can trap all signals (except `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP`) inside the script itself. Take a look at the Python [signal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) module.

Comment: could you explain exactly what signal it sends when I press ALT+F4?

Comment: ALT-F4 inside a shell doesn't usually send any signal. Your window manager, though, probably sends a `SIGTERM` to the shell, which in turn sends a `SIGHUP` to all child processes of that shell.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the program text of `left.py` you can do something like this:

```
trap "" INT
```

That is, do nothing when SIGINT is raised.  You can use TERM too if you want.  I'm not sure which signal exactly is raised by Alt+F4 on your platform, and you mention SIGABRT and SIGKILL as well; you cannot ignore SIGKILL.